# I am trying to add all XSS validation in my project,Added below Parameter validation filter in Web.xm, Do I still need to add HTML Sanitizer?

Tags: html, xss, owasp, html-sanitizing, antisamy

I am trying to add all XSS validation in my project, I have  added below Parameter validation filter in Web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>ParameterValidationFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.matthewcasperson.validation.filter.ParameterValidationFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>configFile</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/xml/pvf.xml</param-value>
  </init-param> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>ParameterValidationFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Do I still need to add HTML Sanitizer in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is pretty old Query.. but i would like to answer it.. Sanitizer is basically used to clean the input , but usually sanitizing the input is only good when it do not effect the outcome , so as Parameter validation filter provides default sanitization of only removing whitespace ,i dont think you need to use any thing else .

But still it depends on project to project , I don't usually recommend sanitization